# Implement UI to delete/forward individual messages

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am curious to know how to implement something like this, where you can forward or delete individual messages. In my case, I want to do the same for adding/deleting selected users in a list
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can delete whole threads by swiping to the left and delete will appear. You can delete

individual messages within a thread by holding finger on the message and tap on more and

then tick the messages you want gone and tap rubbish bin. Or in another way, you can have a

try of [iPhone Data Eraser](http://www.recovery-ipad.com/iphone-data-eraser.html) to [delete all messages on iPhone](http://www.recovery-ipad.com/delete-messages-on-iphone.html).

Answer (score 0):

The table in your screenshot is in edit mode. Thus you have to enter edit mode (set `editing` to `YES`) and modify the editing mode views by overriding `layoutSubviews` display the proper icons. Also, when entering editing mode, create a `UIToolBar` with the two buttons.